# Wanting to make an arrow animation to expand or collapse the link's sublinks list ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-scroll

First time the function executes correctly, when clicking on button all times afterwards - no. I think it gets terminated somewhere.
I think that in some of the checkpoints the value for some reason is null, and maybe that is why it isn;t executing, ebacsie first time it always executes correctly, and all times afterwards - no. And all times afterwards I don't see the console log of "Function almost finished executing"

Expected behaviour is to have an icon arrow, onClick on which will open/close the main link's sublinks list in the navigation.

Like this:

icon is ">" and link is  somelink

when somelink gets clicked, the appearance of navigation I want to be like: "<" somelink link1 link2 link3 (so that submenu open)

I'm using React hooks. Please help me with that, what am I doing wrong?

```
    const ServiceConditions = () => {
      const [arrowIsClicked, setArrowIsClicked] = React.useState(false);
  const handleSublinksExpandCollapse = (e : React.MouseEvent<SVGSVGElement>) => {
    console.log("arrow is clicked");
    if (arrowIsClicked) return;
    setArrowIsClicked(true);
    if ((e.target as HTMLElement).style.transform === "rotate(0deg)") {
      (e.target as HTMLElement).style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
     
      if (!e.target) console.log(e.target); return
      const parent = (e.target as HTMLElement).parentNode;
      if (!parent) console.log(e.target); return 
      const nextSibling = parent.nextSibling;
      if (!nextSibling) console.log(e.target); return 
      (nextSibling as HTMLElement).style.display = "block";
      console.log("function has almost done executing")
      setArrowIsClicked(false)
      
    } else {  setArrowIsClicked(true); (e.target as HTMLElement).style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
    
    if (!e.target) console.log(e.target); return 
    const parent = (e.target as HTMLElement).parentNode;
    if (!parent) console.log(e.target); return 
    const nextSibling = parent.nextSibling;
    if (!nextSibling) console.log(e.target); return
    (nextSibling as HTMLElement).style.display = "none"; setArrowIsClicked(false); }
   
  }
    
      return (
          <Container>
            {    isDesktop &&
              <><NavigationContainer>
              <StyledScrollSpy
              scrollTargetIds={["section_1", "section_2", "section_3"]}
              offset={100}
              activeNavClass="is-active"
              scrollDuration="1000"
              headerBackground="true"
          >
              <List>
                  <MainRef><Line1><MainRefTypography variant="body1"><a href="#">Home</a></MainRefTypography><IconStyled id="ad-ap" onClick={(e : React.MouseEvent<SVGSVGElement>) => {handleSublinksExpandCollapse(e)}}></IconStyled></Line1><div><LinksInsideList>
                    <MainRef><LinkInsideTypography variant="body4"><a href="#section_1">Section 1</a></LinkInsideTypography></MainRef>
                  <MainRef><LinkInsideTypography variant="body4"><a href="#section_2">Section 2</a></LinkInsideTypography></MainRef>
                  <MainRef><LinkInsideTypography variant="body4"><a href="#section_3">Section 3</a></LinkInsideTypography></MainRef>
                  </LinksInsideList></div></MainRef>
                  
              </List>
              </StyledScrollSpy>
          
          </NavigationContainer></>    }
                    <Articles>
                      <PageName variant={isDesktop ? "h3" : "h1"}>SERVICE CONDITIONS</PageName>
                      <Bar align={BarAlign.Left} />
                      <Spacing mobile={3} desktop={3}/>
                        <div style={{"height": "400px", width: "100%"}}><span>Welcome!</span></div>
                        <div id="section_1" style={{"height": "500px", width: "100%"}}><span>Section 1</span></div>
                        <div id="section_2" style={{"height": "500px", width: "100%"}}><span>Section 2</span></div>
                        <div id="section_3" style={{"height": "500px", width: "100%"}}><span>Section 3</span></div>
                        </Articles>
            </Container>
      );
    };
    export default ServiceConditions;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think the problem is with this:

"if (arrowIsClicked) return;"

First it runs entirely setting arrowIsClicked to true, and afterwards at that line it exits every time.

Here is a simple way to implement a button that has the arrow rotating based on open/close state:

```
function CollapsibleButton() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <button
      style={{
        display: "inline-block",
      }}
      // Simply setting open to the opposite value.
      onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
    >
      <span
        style={{
          // This makes it feel animated:
          transition: "transform 200ms linear",
          // This rotates the element:
          transform: `rotateZ(${open ? 0 : "180deg"})`,
          display: "inline-block",
        }}
      >
        {"<"}
      </span>
      Click me
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but why do you think it exits every time afeterwards? I set it to false at the very end of the function, please explain me if possible

Comment: Your solution is cool, but I will have a lot of such links and sublinks inthe future, so I'm looking for a more dynamic way to do that

Comment: When you say "return" in a function, it will exit it immediately, and the code under that will not be executed. As i mentioned this line: "if (arrowIsClicked) return;" will exit the function every time and the part where you set it to false will not be reached. This is a Component so it can be used dynamically. Just add all the custom parts as a prop and then you could have as many CollapsibleButton as you wish.

Comment: Thank you! Have a great day!